# Using GET with a form

Tags: php

So I have a form which has a drop down list, when the submit button is pressed the script task4.php is called. My problem is that I can use the whole option that is selected, however I only need the tid. How do I get just the tid and use it task4.php?

```
<form action="task4.php" method="get">
 <select>
 <?php
        foreach($results as $row) {
            echo "<option>".$row[tid].", ".$row[category].", ".$row[division].", ".$row[clubID].", ".$row[name]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is what I've got in task 4 and it isn't working:

```
 if (isset($_GET['tid'])) {
 $tid = $_GET['tid'];
 }
```

Comment: Add `name attribute` to your select box `<select name="tid">`

Comment: When I used this in task4.php won't this just return the whole select, i.e the tid the category the division etc. Is there a way to separate these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible (perhaps even necessary) that in the absence of a `value` the browser is sending the text contents of the selected `option` with the form data.

Just give the `option` a `value`:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row[tid]."\">" ...
```

Additionally, that `select` should really have a `name` (I don't even see how it could have worked without one):

```
<select name="tid">
```

Comment: Ok, I've given it a value, now how would I get that value in task4.php? what would go in the $_GET[???]

Comment: You will fing this in $_GET['tid']

Comment: Oh great, just let me try this :) Thank you